# Dynamics AX 2009 -> videos step by step

Tags: axapta

I have got problem with "Dynamics AX 2009" the most difficult is with "General Ledger" when I check network I didn`t find important information about this topic. I need  videos about "Dynamics AX 2009" **but step by step from begining to advanced things** and also something about relation in "General Ledger" for example "General Jurnals" are related with "Tax" because....? This is very important for me I have to understand this softweare.

Why you giving me minus points? This is normal question.

Comment: What if we haven't seen the video?

Comment: @Code Gary I will have problem.

Comment: I think OP wants videos **about** axapta.

Comment: @RafalPolandBeginner You've got a lot of downvotes on your other questions; if the question really is "very important", then it's important enough to put in more effort **clearly describing the problem to be solved**. Also, it's bad form to always write that the question is "very important"; we're here to help, but you being in a desperate situation is more your problem than ours :)

Comment: @beerbajay with this point about "very important" I can agree with you but in my opinion this is clear question. If we speak about minus points in my opinion a lot of people giving this points to fast and all the time people create new accounts in this service. For example 10 minutes ago I have got only one question with minus points. Now I have got here minus points and in another old question I get probably for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for videos why not try Youtube, as it is the most likely place to find anything?

Or Google "Dynamics AX 2009 - General Ledger Tutorials" and check the results you get.

The other thing to do is actually post up what your problem is as there is a chance someone else has came across the same thing and will be able to help...

Comment: If you will know how difficult is (dynamics AX) you will not send this stupid idea.

Comment: Well whenever I get stuck with something I look through my resources and then failing that I post the question on here. Also the suggestion of youtube is not a bad one, there are dynamics ax 2009 videos on there. The suggestion of Google'ing your query is not a bad one, as there will be other people who are stuck with similar things. Finally the suggestion of actually telling us what you are stuck with is not a bad idea as we do not have a clue what you actually need help with, General Ledger is quite large you know.

Comment: Also when people try to help it is not very wise to claim their ideas are "stupid", it doesn't really give people much drive to help you. And as a matter of fact I do know how difficult it is I've only been working with Dynamics for 1 year and I am fully aware how frustrating it can be.

Comment: frustrating is very good word. If at the beginning of my question I get minus points for question and for my old questions I also get for this question minus points. I ask only about videos step by step for "dynamics ax 2009" I am sorry if I write to much but - (frustrating)